# How long should confirmation (spendable amount) take?

Tags: transactions, multibit, confirmations

My transaction already has 24 confirmations at blockchain.info, and the transaction is correctly recorded in Multibit.

But there is no "spendable amount".

I've already "Reset Blockchain And Transactions", but to now avail.  I've closed MultiBit and restarted, to no avail.

I'm sure I've have connections (or else the transaction wouldn't have recorded), but I don't know about how to check how many nodes Multibit is connected to, or where to find out, or what to do about it.

I'm new to BitCoin, so I'm here to learn . . .

Is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not see the balance row with 'Spendable' appearing, it is because ALL your bitcoin is spendable. The row is just made invisible in this case.

It's only shown when the total is different (normally when you have incoming bitcoin that hasn't confirmed yet)